# Как сделать вибрацию при переходе на другую страницу используя switch value=true?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-native, redux-thunk

Телефону необходимо вибрировать при переходе на другую страницу приложения если значение switch сохраняется как true. Как это сделать и правильно ли я прописываю функцию? Буду благодарна любой помощи! Вот мой код:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Slider, Switch, Button, View, Vibration } from 'react-native';

import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { saveSettings} from '../redux/reducers';

const DURATION = 1000;

class Settings extends React.Component {
  
  saveSettings = (red,green,blue,vibrate) => {
    var settings = this.props.bgColor
    this.props.dispatch(saveSettings(settings));
  }
  
  handleRed = (red) => {
    this.props.dispatch(saveSettings(red));
  }
  
  handleGreen = (green) => {
    this.props.dispatch(saveSettings(green));
  }
  
  handleBlue = (blue) => {
    this.props.dispatch(saveSettings(blue));
  }
  
  handleVibrate = (vibrate) => {
    if(vibrate===true){
    this.setState({
      Vibration.vibrate(DURATION)
    })
  }, esle {
    this.setState({
      Vibration.cancel()
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Slider
          value={this.state.red}
          onValueChange={this.handleRed}
          minimumValue={0}
          maximumValue={255}
        />
        <Slider
          value={this.state.green}
          onValueChange={this.handleGreen}
          minimumValue={0}
          maximumValue={255}
        />
        <Slider
          value={this.state.blue}
          onValueChange={this.handleBlue}
          minimumValue={0}
          maximumValue={255}
        />
        <Switch
          value={this.state.vibrate}
          onValueChange={this.handleVibrate}
        />
        <Button
          title="Save"
          onPress={this.saveSettings}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Так же вот коды actions, reducers и combine:

```js
//actions
export function saveSettings(red,green,blue,vibrate){
  return {
    type:"SAVE_SETTINGS",
    red:red,
    blue:blue,
    green:green,
    vibrate:vibrate
  }
}

//combine
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { saveSettings } from './reducers';

const myApp = combineReducers({
  saveSettings
});

export default myApp;


//reducers
const bgColor = {
  red:255,
  green:255,
  blue:255,
  vibrate:false
};

export function saveSettings(state = bgColor, action) {
  let obj = Object.assign({}, state);
  
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SAVE_SETTINGS":
      obj.red = action.red;
      return obj;
      
      obj.green = action.green;
      return obj;
      
      obj.blue = action.blue;
      return obj;
      
      obj.vibrate = action.vibrate;
      return obj;
    
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял... 
Вам необходимо глобально хранить vibration в redux и в месте перехода еще раз проверять state/redux store...

```
handleVibrate = (vibrate) => {
  if (vibrate===true){
    Vibration.vibrate(DURATION); 
  } esle {
    Vibration.cancel()
  }
  this.setState({ vibrate });
}
```

еще нужно проверить подключение компонента к redux - connect()

Comment: Т.е. мне надо в каждом компоненте прописывать вибрацию или только в настройках?

Comment: если это необходимо – вибрировать каждый раз при переходе на другой экран, я бы сделал это где-то рядом с навигацией. конкретно что-то порекомендовать не могу. т.к. это сильно зависит от того как у вас работает навигация, на чем она построена (библиотека, компонент)

Comment: Спасибо большое!